# Problemas con un ARRAY en javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo el siguiente problema y es que intento de poder recoger los datos guardados en una variable array (var datos = []). Pero cuando un console.log el resultado está metido dentro de un [] en la consola, en vez de salirme todo. Os adjunto una foto a ver si podéis echarme una mano! Gracias de antemano![image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon `monstrarDatos(precios, nombreING)` debajo de `nombreING.push...`. Es una operación asincrona, creo que por eso te muestra otros datos.

Comment: nombreING es un arreglo, es normal que salga `[ ]` en consola, pero ahí deberían de estar los nombres.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Es importante destacar que el código y mensajes de error o log deben ir en formato de texto y no en imagen. Por favor, haz clic en [edit] y modifica lo que haga falta. También es importante que leas [mcve], de esta forma tendrás más oportunidades de recibir respuestas y evitas que tu pregunta termine cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.